# Find element by classname and click on element within javascript rendered site using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I searched stack overflow and tried some solutions but could not make it work.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe";
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/");
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
tt = driver.find_element_by_class_name('zafg3t-1')
print(tt)

driver.quit()
```

The class name `zafg3t-1` is the search area class, I can see in browser, but selenium cant find the class. So I unable to click.

What is my mistake here?

Comment: should i put dot in front of className? as it is not `css_selector` instead class_name

Comment: @Firelord `zafg3t-1` and `gaWePq` are dynamically generated. Won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Classnames like *`zafg3t-1`*, *`gaWePq`*, etc are dynamic generated and would change after a considerable amount of time and even may be the next time you access the [site](https://coinmarketcap.com/) afresh.

---

### Solution

To click within the ***Search*** box  you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.cmc-cookie-policy-banner__close"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-text='Use to trigger search']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cmc-cookie-policy-banner__close']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Search']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: coinmarketcap]

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But the code you have provided can not grab the element. Here is the matter. Dont know why, it can not grab the element

Comment: What do mean by _grab the element_? Can you just copy/paste the lines of code from this answer and retest?

Comment: Both in css_selector and xpath `cmc-cookie-policy-banner__close` line, these are not showing error, but not clicking anything too. 
And in both css_selector and xpath "Search" option line, triggering timeout error. 
`raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)`

Comment: Here is full error: 

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Search']"))).click()
  File "F:\python\installed2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: